# .src=Array[i] doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to make a simple slide show and i'm trying to make the current src become the new array but it doesn't seem to work. I know i made an error somewhere but i can't find it. Help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
images = ["1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png"];

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").src= images[i] ;
}


</script>
</head>

<body>

<img id="demo" src="1.png" style="width:500px;height:350px;border: 2px solid grey;">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please `var` your variables.

Comment: Note that even when you fix the `images` versus `cars` problem, that loop will just set your demo element to the last image in the array. (At least it'll go through the whole array, but so quickly that you'll only really see the last image.)

Comment: @nnnnnn what way should i do this?

Comment: If the idea is for each picture to stay for some number of seconds use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeh i know that :) but why do the src of the images do not change

Comment: because script is executed before DOM is loaded and therefore `document.getElementById('demo');` returns null.

Comment: JS can only access elements that have been parsed, so elements defined above the script element, or JS running from an onload or DOM ready handler. So you might mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/1trngzvh/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a guess, but this is probably what you want: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/rsIKi

1. Add script to `DOMContentLoaded`
2. use `window.setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in the *for* . You are using *cars* variable instead of *images*:

```
for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
```

Regards.